# Swift: Run animation in accordance/at same rate as swipe?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I am trying to achieve an interactive animation/transition affect with my view set up here:

[image]

When the user swipes up, I run these animations to make it look like the top bar is moving up with the arrow, etc and then reset these animations:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.8, animations: {
            self.halfBtn.center.y -= self.screenSize.height

            }, completion: nil)


        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {
            self.arrow.center.y -= self.screenSize.height * (100/568)
            self.arrow.alpha = CGFloat(0)
            self.aboutText.textColor = UIColor(red: 70/255, green: 70/255, blue: 70/255, alpha: 1)
            //self.skyText.textColor = UIColor(red: 233/255, green: 233/255, blue: 233/255, alpha: 1)
            //self.halfBtn.center.y -= self.screenSize.height * (100/568)

            }, completion: {
                (value: Bool) in
                //after
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://www.troublemakertechnologies.com")!)

                self.resetAnim()

        })

    }

    func resetAnim()
    {
        var dispatchTime: dispatch_time_t = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            // your function here

            self.arrow.center.y = self.screenSize.height * (393/480)
            self.arrow.alpha = CGFloat(1)
            self.halfBtn.center.y = 0
            self.aboutText.textColor = UIColor(red: 233/255, green: 233/255, blue: 233/255, alpha: 1)
            //self.skyText.textColor = UIColor(red: 70/255, green: 70/255, blue: 71/255, alpha: 1)
        })

    }
```

So as it is, I have partially achieved the desired effect (arrow fades out, bar moves up):

[image]

But if the user isn't swiping particularly fast, the animation loses its "feel" and moves too fast to look as though it is dependent on the swipe. I need to know how to run my animations IN ACCORDANCE with the speed of the user's swipe.

Is there a way to get the rate of the user's swipe and plug that value in as the duration somehow? Or do my animations in increments based on swipe speed?

Id like the animation to be "responsive" and running at the same time as the users swipe - what is the correct way to accomplish this?

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/interactive-animations/

Comment: This is quite a tricky proposition, I have battled with this quite a bit. Currently I'm in the process of finalizing a whole framework that uses a spring/damping system to perform this, taking into account the current position of the view and the velocity of a pan gesture recognizer.

Comment: You probably want to not use an animation, and actually just alter the views' properties based on the _delta y_ distance from where the swipe gesture began. This way, you can actually base the views' changes on the user's input, and you won't run a ridiculous number of animations repeatedly.

Comment: How would I do that exactly? Could you provide an example?

Comment: Does anybody know how to do this in Android ?